# How can I fix errors (red texts) in XML which are preventing from showing preview or running the app on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout

[image]

My laptop is dead so I tried to open my project to my friend's laptop but i cant seem to see what i made, i tried to **search** one xml file...

[image]

But it showed some **red statements**. I can't even see the design.
*Please help me*. :<

Comment: What happens if you try the "hammer" icon in the tool bar? (Make project)
Also, does the files appear if you switch from "Android" to "Project files" in the dropdown menu on the sidebar?

Comment: I switched "android" to "project", i can see the files but when i open the xml files, there are also red statements :<

Comment: @GeneRoseGèrilla try my steps. it will surely work after that.

Comment: Also, i can't click the hammer icon

Comment: I'll try @SuryakantBharti thanks

Comment: In the tags you mention Android Studio, but according to the first screenshot, you open the project in IntelliJ.

Comment: @Benoit yes i'm using android studio, through intellij.

Comment: That could explain the problem: You have created the project under Android Studio, but you try to import it on IntelliJ IDEA on your friend's laptop. **Try to install the real Android Studio** on your friend's laptop.

Comment: @Benoit i created the project in my laptop using also intellij with android studio. it was fine, how come i cant open it in my friend's laptop? *I tried to re-install intellij and the android sdk but still having the same problem*

Comment: What do you mean *intellij with android studio* ? Although they share the same code base, these are different products. [Android studio](https://developer.android.com/studio) / [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/)

Comment: @GeneRoseGèrilla please share screenshot of **Run -> Edit Configuration** screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda tried to **close the project** and tried to **import the project**. 
Now i can see the the files inside the app java module.
Thank you guys :>>

Comment: I told you to re-import the project.
If you ever face issues with Android Studio, there are fixed set of steps which solves the problem 95 percent of the time. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Basic steps to try:**

1. File -> Settings -> Version Control -> disable the VCS

[image]

2. File -> Sync with File System
3. File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files
4. Build -> Clean Project
5. Build -> Rebuild Project
6. File -> Invalidate Cashes / Restart

**Solving No facet found in module:**

1. Remove the .idea folder and any .iml files
2. Re-import the project into Android Studio.

Comment: I can't see where the "disable the VCS" is

Comment: @GeneRoseGèrilla updated the answer about how to disable (select project -> click "-")

Comment: If it is already disabled, do other steps... let me know if it is fixed or not...

Comment: When i try to run or debug the project, in the "edit configuration" says that there is no module. if i try to run/debug in anyways, an error says , "No Android facet found for app"

Comment: Also i cant seem to see the other options you suggested @SuryakantBharti

Comment: the first option you suggested, i have an empty directory so...

Comment: So, re-import as a new project.